# What if we eliminate the compactness of one of these sets?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Prove that if $A, B$ are compact sets in topological spaces $X,Y$
> respectively s.t $A\times B$ is contained an open set $N$ of the product topology $X\times
> Y$ then there exists open sets $U\in X$ and $V\in Y$ s.t $A\times
>  B\subset U\times V\subset N$.

Actually I already proved this problem. But I still want an example to show that if we eliminate one of the compactness of $A,B$, the statement is not true. Could someone give me an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, $A = \{0\}$, $B = Y$. Then the open set $N = \{(x, y)\in X\times Y:|y|\le (x^2+1)^{-1}\}$ does not contain any open rectangle containing $A\times B$.